# Widget stops receiving USER_PRESENT intents after deep sleep

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget that updates the time every minute using a repeating alarm. The widget also registers in the manifest for the USER_PRESENT intent and when this is received, it checks if the time updating alarm is running; if not, it starts it.

The above works for most devices. On some devices though, it looks like the widget stops receiving the USER_PRESENT intent when the device goes into deep sleep (the repeating alarm also stops firing). The widget process is not killed by the system because clicking on the widget causes it to start working again.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Here is the widget receiver definition:

```
<receiver android:name=".timeWidget" >        
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT`
Broadcast Action: Sent when the user is present after device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone).

So it means you will not get this broadcast when device is locked.

Comment: I know about this. I mean that when the user unlocks the device (after it has gone into deep sleep), the USER_PRESENT message is not received...